# Failed to consume input event.Android

Tags: java, android

This is the error i often see in my application.Can anyone know ,any idea ,what is the reason for this error.

the error has two lines :

```
     consumer ~ Error -1 pinning ashmem fd 69
' ~ Failed to consume input event.  status=-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed similar bug in app I work on. The problem was in buggy native code that was closing file descriptors twice,- it means it first was closing it in Close method and later invoking Close again in destructor with no checking if file descriptor was already closed.

Native `open` function returns as file descriptor, a first free lowest number. So from time to time above bug was closing descriptor that got reused between one Close and the second invocation of it. It mostly happend that this descriptor was used by parcel.

While searching for solution to this bug, I found that this errors happen in two cases:

1. when there are too many file descriptors being open, which might suggest that there is a leak
2. when code is closing file descriptors twice

debugging this is not easy, its hard to reproduce, also if you dont use native code then its even harder to understand the problem.

If you have no native code, then this bug might occur when trying to communicate with window that was closed. Like you have not closed some dialog but closed activity owning it. I never experienced such case but, I am adding it as a hint.